# DAC Inherits from other DAC, ReportDesigner error

Tags: acumatica

This topic was covered well at this link:

[Create DAC that inherits from other DAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736781/create-dac-that-inherits-from-other-dac)

I am getting this error with a Report (.rpx) when attempting to visit it on the website:

```
GenericArguments[0], 'MyNamespace.DAC1', on 'PX.Data.PXCache`1[TNode]' violates the constraint of type 'TNode'.
```

Specifically, DAC1 contains only the "audit fields" such as CreatedByID, LastModifiedDateTime, etc.  DAC2 inherits from DAC1 and only DAC2 implements IBqlTable. The MS SQL table maps to DAC2 only and it contains all fields combined.  A ListView page works well for maintenance of table data, but 
the report will not render if DAC1 fields are included in the report design.

I have tried adding [PXTable] to DAC2 but no luck. I wish to avoid redefining/overriding the audit fields of DAC1 into DAC2. Am I overlooking something? Should I abandon the use of DAC1 altogether? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to have DAC1 which contains only the "audit fields"? Why aren't you moving them to DAC2 and removing DAC1 at all?

Comment: The idea is re-use of DAC1 as a base class for other DACs having audit fields in their underlying SQL tables. It is an idea being explored but not yet adopted. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you can't do this approach in the current versions of Acumatica. I haven't checked but I think the SQL Query which is being generated for the Report is trying to get the Audit Fields from the DAC1 table instead of using DAC2. You can check that with Request Profiler in Acumatica and MS SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you, @SamvelPetrosov. Not a problem.

Comment: Even if you could do it, consider whether implementing a 're-usable' pattern is worth causing potential incompatibility problems when you or someone else try to modify/understand your code. Most code examples and tutorials are provided in the form of simple DAC so people helping you will have an easier time dealing with simple DAC.